# Why is IntelliSense auto complete not working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

Opening from start menu or from unreal engine 4 the auto complete function doesn't work at all.

I have tried uninstalling visual studio code with revo uninstaller and going into appdata to clean up the remaining folder and files left. I have tried re doing my whole unreal engine 4 course work from the resource I was given.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.
#include "BullCowCartridge.h"

void UBullCowCartridge::BeginPlay() // When the game starts
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    PrintLine("Welcome to Bull Cows!");  
    PrintLine("Press enter to continue...");
}

void UBullCowCartridge::OnInput(const FString& Input) // When the player hits enter
{
   ClearScreen();
   FString HiddenWord 
}
```

Typing either FString or PrintLine doesn't give the auto complete when hitting tab.

Comment: Click on one of lines of code already written to call the `PrintLine` function or the `FString` type and hit F12 (or if you've changed hotkeys, whatever is Go To Definition).  Does it find the definition?  If it doesn't find the definition, you are probably missing some #include directives at the top of your file, or haven't configured the right include search directories.

Comment: Yes it finds the definition.